# Has_parent query returns no hits in elasticsearch 6.5.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to find all children of parents that match certain query using the following has_parent query:

```
GET my_index*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "threat",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "type.keyword": {
            "value": "ip"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it returns no hits, even with a match_all query.

The mapping of the index is as follows:

```
"my_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
          "@timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "@version" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "asn_info" : {
            "properties" : {
              "as_org" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "asn" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "campaign" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "category" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "category_description" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "confidence" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "criticity" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "detection_date" : {
            "type" : "float"
          },
          "feed" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "feeds" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "geo" : {
            "properties" : {
              "city_name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "country_code2" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "country_code3" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "country_name" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "fields" : {
                  "keyword" : {
                    "type" : "keyword",
                    "ignore_above" : 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "latitude" : {
                "type" : "float"
              },
              "longitude" : {
                "type" : "float"
              }
            }
          },
          "hierarchy" : {
            "type" : "join",
            "eager_global_ordinals" : true,
            "relations" : {
              "threat" : "date"
            }
          },
          "host" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "ip" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "ip_address" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "port" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "subcategory" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "tags" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see, the hierarchy field is a join field, with "threat" defined as parent of "date". I don't see any problem with this. Does anyone know what could be happening?